# Service multiple connection on NodeJS webserver

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a web server running using Node.js with express and socket.io It displays real-time temperature information and allows for real-time control of some basic hardware controllers.

Each time I connect to the server from a different client, a new instance of the content is delivered as opposed to delivering the last configured instance or state.

Things work fine when just one client is used, but I need to be able to monitor the temperatures and control status from multiple clients.

How can I make sure that no matter which client accesses the server, they all see the same state of the server?

Server code below:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var socketServer = require('socket.io').listen(http);
var fs = require('fs');
var csv_stream = fs.createWriteStream("tempLog.csv");
var time_handler = require('moment');

SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort;

var serialPort;
var portName = '/dev/ttyACM0'; //change this to your Arduino port
var sendData = "";
var debug = false; 

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/interface.html')
});

socketServer.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('run', function(data){
      serialPort.write('Z' + data + 'A');
      console.log('write to ard');
      console.log('Z' + data + 'A');
    });
    socket.on('stop', function(data){
      serialPort.write('Y' + data + 'B');
      console.log('write to ard');
      console.log('Y' + data + 'B');
    });
    socket.on('configure', function(data){
      serialPort.write('X' + data + 'C');
      console.log('write to ard');
      console.log('X' + data + 'C');
    });
    socket.on('temperatureValues', function(data){
        serialPort.write(data);
        console.log('write data to ard');
        console.log(data);      
    });
    socket.on('timeValues', function(data){
        serialPort.write(data);
        console.log('write data to ard');
        console.log(data);      
    });
});

serialListener(debug);

function SocketIO_serialemit(sendData){      
    //console.log(sendData.length);     

    if(sendData.length >= 14)
    {   
        var s_data = sendData.split(",");
        socketServer.emit('temp1',{'temp': s_data[0]});
        socketServer.emit('temp2',{'temp': s_data[1]});
        socketServer.emit('temp3',{'temp': s_data[2]});
        csv_stream.write(time_handler().format('HH:mm:ss') + ',');
        csv_stream.write(s_data[0] + ',' + s_data[1] + ',' + s_data[2]);
        csv_stream.write('\n');
        //csv_stream.end(); 
    }

    else{
        console.log("Error");
        //var s_data = sendData.split(",");
        //console.log(s_data[0]);
        //console.log(s_data[1]);
        //console.log(s_data[2]);   
    }
}

// Listen to serial port
function serialListener(debug)
{
    var receivedData = "";
    serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, {
        baudrate: 9600,
        // defaults for Arduino serial communication
         dataBits: 8,
         parity: 'none',
         stopBits: 1,
         flowControl: false
    });

    serialPort.on("open", function () {
      console.log('open serial communication');
            // Listens to incoming data
            serialPort.on('data', function(data) {

            if (data.toString() == "X")
            {
                console.log("Control Done");
                socketServer.emit('Completed',{'key': data.toString()});
            }

            if (data.toString()[0] == "S")
            {
                console.log("Stage Done");
                socketServer.emit('Stage',{'key': data.toString()[0]});
            }

            receivedData += data.toString();

              //console.log(receivedData);
              if (receivedData .indexOf('E') >= 0 && receivedData .indexOf('T') >= 0) {
               sendData = receivedData .substring(receivedData .indexOf('T') + 1, receivedData .indexOf('E'));        
            receivedData = '';
            SocketIO_serialemit(sendData);
             }


        });  
    });
}

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000')  
});

app.use(require('express').static(__dirname + '/public')); //sever static files (css, js, fonts, etc.)
```

Comment: Can you share your server's code with us please?

Comment: I added the server code, thanks.